# User location coordinates being null when passed into url

Tags: java, android, mobile

I'm building a simple five-day weather forecast Android app using the open weather map API. I am trying to insert the user coordinates into my request URL using the Google Play Services but values for latitude and longitude are null when I am passing them into the URL. I am just wondering if there is any way to solve this by passing the coordinates from the onConnected methods of the Google Play Services.

**MainActivity**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements OnConnectionFailedListener {

private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
private Location mLastLocation;
private String latitude;
private String longitude;
private String requestUrl = "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?lat="+latitude+"&lon="+longitude+"&units=metric&APPID={insert api key here}";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // Create an instance of GoogleAPIClient.
    if (mGoogleApiClient == null) {
        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                .build();
    }

    new WeatherAsyncTask().execute(requestUrl);
}

public void updateUi(final ArrayList<Weather> weather) {
    // Find a reference to the {@link ListView} in the layout
    ListView weatherListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);

    // Create a new {@link ArrayAdapter} of earthquakes
    WeatherAdapter adapter = new WeatherAdapter(this, weather);

    // Set the adapter on the {@link ListView}
    // so the list can be populated in the user interface
    weatherListView.setAdapter(adapter);
}

private class WeatherAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, ArrayList<Weather>> {
    protected ArrayList<Weather> doInBackground(String... requestUrl) {
        // Dont perform the request if there is no URL, or first is null
        if (requestUrl.length < 1 || requestUrl[0] == null) {
            return null;
        }

        ArrayList<Weather> weather = QueryUtils.fetchWeatherData(requestUrl[0]);

        return weather;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<Weather> weather) {
        // if there is no result do nothing
        if (weather == null) {
            return;
        }

        updateUi(weather);
    }
}

// if connection not established to google play services
@Override
public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult result) {
    // An unresolvable error has occurred and a connection to Google APIs
    // could not be established. Display an error message, or handle
    // the failure silently

    // ...
}

// get latitude and longitude of last known location when connected to google play services
public void onConnected(Bundle connectionHint) {
    try {
        mLastLocation = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(mGoogleApiClient);
    } catch (SecurityException e) {
        Log.e("MainActivity", "Security exception thrown", e);
    }
    if (mLastLocation != null) {
        latitude = String.valueOf(mLastLocation.getLatitude());
        longitude = String.valueOf(mLastLocation.getLongitude());
    }
}
```

}

When the app is run, I get a NullPointerException. I realize that the values for latitude and longitude are null but I am not sure how to retrieve them correctly. Thanks for any help, I'm fairly new at android development.

P.S. I have omitted the API key from the URL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please refer this guide : [Retrieving-Location-with-LocationServices-API](https://guides.codepath.com/android/Retrieving-Location-with-LocationServices-API)

First of all `LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation` will return you a location if any recent app used location(device has recent location) otherwise it will return `null`.

So in case of null value you must check it inside `onConnected` .
For getting non null location you must listen devices location.(FusedLocationApi, LocationManager ...)

Also you must check permission for `Android M` higher devices, luckily you are using `FusedLocationApi` inside your `Activity`.

Basic sample of my code :

```
@Override
public void onConnected(@Nullable Bundle bundle) {
    if( HelperUtils.isGpsOpen(getApplicationContext()) ) {
        startListenLocation();
    }
}

@Override
public void startListenLocation() {
    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        //ask permission whatever you want to do
    } else {
        if(mGoogleApiClient==null) {
            buildGoogleApiClient();
        } else {
            if(mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
                mLocationRequest = new LocationRequest();
                mLocationRequest.setInterval(UPDATE_INTERVAL);
                mLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(FASTEST_INTERVAL);
                mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_BALANCED_POWER_ACCURACY);
                mLocationRequest.setSmallestDisplacement(DISPLACEMENT);
                Location mCurrentLocation = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(mGoogleApiClient);
                //here I am checking null thats where you get null
                if(mCurrentLocation!=null) {
                    mPresenter.onNewLocation(getDeviceId(),mCurrentLocation.getLatitude(),mCurrentLocation.getLongitude());
                }
                // then I am tracking user location  ,  this will trigger onLocationChanged method when a new location arrived so you can handle new location
                LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest, this);
            } else {
                if(!mGoogleApiClient.isConnecting())
                buildGoogleApiClient();
            }
        }

    }

}

@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    // I am just checking null again, more cautious I am :)
    if(location!=null) // handle it
}
```

Then important part is remove location requests when your `Activity's` `onPause` or `onDestroy` :

```
if(mGoogleApiClient!=null){
        LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.removeLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, this);
        if(mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
}
```

Comment: I have implemented the location but the latitude and longitude strings are null when passed into the requestUrl. Why is this ? Thanks

Comment: @KeelanByrne do you have appropriate permissions on your manifest

Comment: <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />

These are my permissions

Comment: @KeelanByrne can you add this too : `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />` and try

Comment: That did not change anything. I am still getting an error response code of 400 because the Strings latitude and longitude are null

Comment: I actually found the solution, I needed to request permissions on app launch. I then assigned the url in the onConnected method and called the  WeatherAsyncTask.execute() method from the onConnected method also. Thanks for all  your help :)

Comment: I'm glad you find a solution